# How to create an index programmatically for a dynamic Mongo collection? ( Java Spring Data MongoDB )

Tags: java, mongodb

I need help with this, here is my document class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(collection = "#{@dateService.getCurrentDate()}")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class LogDocument {
    private ObjectId _id;
    private String log;
    private String key;
}
```

As you can see my collection name is dynamic depending on date, e.g. `2020-10-05`.

I want to create a unique index on the key. HOW?

When the collection name is fixed I can simply do the following in the mongo Configuration class:

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps("{collection name}").ensureIndex(indexDefinition.unique());
```

but since the collection is dynamic, I need a way to trigger a `PostConstruct` for every time a new collection is created so that I can create the index.

Comment: If you are delegating the collection name to spring maybe you should let spring manage your index with the annotation Indexed and don't forget to enable autoIndexCreation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simply using annotations

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
//For Compound index: 
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(name = "key_app", def = "{'key' : 1, 'app': 1}")
})
@Document(collection = "#{@dateService.getCurrentDate()}")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class LogDocument {
    private ObjectId _id;
    private String log;
    //For a unique index on one field: 
    // @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String key;
    private String app;
}
```